# Error in reading Json response

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I"m trying to to read a json response from my json feed but the log cat shows me this error.. don't know what to do... please help..

/Error - >﹕ org.json.JSONException: Value 
 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

My json response from link is here...

```
{  
 "feed":[  
  {  
     "id":65,
     "name":"Hissam",
     "image":"http://deejay.org/feed/ironman.jpg",
     "status":"Hello thi is hissam",
     "profilePic":"http://deejay.org/feed/profilepic.jpg",
     "timeStamp":"1403375851930",
     "url":"http://google.com"
  },
  {  
     "id":65,
     "name":"Hissam",
     "image":"http://deejay.org/feed/cosmos.jpg",
     "status":"Hello thi is hissam",
     "profilePic":"http://deejay.org/feed/profilepic.jpg",
     "timeStamp":"1403375851930",
     "url":"http://google.com"
  }
 ]
}
```

Here is my JSON code

```
private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
    try {
        JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

        for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

            FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
            item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
            item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

            // Image might be null sometimes
            String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("image");
            item.setImge(image);
            item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
            item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
            item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

            // url might be null sometimes
            String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                    .getString("url");
            item.setUrl(feedUrl);

            feedItems.add(item);
        }
```

Comment: Show us the Java code

Comment: Please post the code that is throwing the exception.

Comment: provide us the json link, i think your json is updated.

Comment: You are parsing the json properly. Please ensure that you are passing the proper `JSONObject` to your `parseJsonFeed()` method.

Comment: @Rah i'm using local server for testing.. i don't have online link to share

Comment: @Suhas bro i've posted the json response.. and i don't see any error in it..   if you can point any error please help..

Comment: May be you are not creating the `JSONObject` from `String` response properly. Are you creating like this `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response)`?

Comment: JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

please check the above code

Comment: Could you please post the logcat? Your `parseJsonFeed()` method works fine and you have to check if you are creating `JSONObject` properly with the `String` response. I think the App is crashing even before it comes to `parseJsonFeed()`.

Comment: this is the case bro, app isn't crashing and nothing shows but just the Toast and this one line in the logcat regarding json string. i'll post the logcat anyway..

Comment: @Suhas  there was a issue with my php script.. 
'header('Content-type: application/json')' was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue by adding

```
  header('Content-type:application/json');
```

to my PHP script. Didn't know header were that important up till now.